# How to open (not save) a generated blob array of a pdf (Intel XDK-Android)?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel-xdk

I want to know a properly and proved way to open (not save) a generated blob array of a pdf with some default app for that (e.g. Adobe reader) if I am developing for Android with Intel XDK and Cordova.

Unsuccessfully I tried this (generated with jspdf):

```
    function createPDF(){
        console.log("generating pdf...");
        var doc = new jsPDF();

        doc.text(20, 20, 'HELLO!');

        doc.setFont("courier");
        doc.setFontType("normal");
        doc.text(20, 30, 'This is a PDF document generated using JSPDF.');
        doc.text(20, 50, 'YES, Inside of cordova!');

        pdfOutput = doc.output();
        console.log(pdfOutput);

        var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(pdfOutput.length);
        var array = new Uint8Array(buffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < pdfOutput.length; i++) {
          array[i] = pdfOutput.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64," + array;
        window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
    }
```

Also I tried a lot of example but nothing works, just in case, none error is shown in console.

Thank you all.

Comment: You appear to be concatenating an `ArrayBuffer` `array` to a string? What does `console.log(array.join(""))` log at `console`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Blob` from `pdfOutput`, then create a `Blob URL` from `Blob` using `URL.createObjectURL()`

```
    var blob = new Blob([pdfOutput], {type:"application/pdf"});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var pdfAsDataUri = url;
    window.open(pdfAsDataUri);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/xt5uVvskmcgSlf13xVVM?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but this in Android open a blank screen with the url and then closes, I tried also with [link]window.open(pdfAsDataUri, '_system', 'location=yes');[link] to open in  a different screen which would be catched to open with Adobe reader but nothing happens.

Comment: I´m using to test the Intel XDK emulator and Andy Android emulator (I dont have a physical Android device), do you think the issue would be for that? Can you help me testing my app in a real Android device?: https://mega.nz/#!vIN1HI6I!PVlCT4ufT2DM_NTUU0w98abOawJdg5CAArw_mXA3PYo   If you agree please try it with "Ir PDF" and then "CREATE PDF" (ignore the other buttons). Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can do it splitting the problem to:

*One button to create the document

*One button to create the pdf content

*One button to write the pdf content into the created document

*One button to open the file

*Only Cordova File plugin

And following and adapting the solution in this post:
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2/issues/60

Later I´ll do a video tutorial because this issue seems to be common and hard to solve.